# Does there exist an injective ring homomorphism $\frac{{\bf Z}[x]}{(x^3(x-3)^3)} \rightarrow M_5 (\bf Z)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Does there exist an injective ring homomorphism $\dfrac{{\bf Z}[x]}{(x^3(x-3)^3)} \rightarrow  M_5 (\bf Z)$ ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose there is an injective ring homomorphism $f:\mathbb Z[X]/(X^3(X-3)^3)\to M_5 (\mathbb Z)$. Then there is an injective ring homomorphism $f:\mathbb Z[X]/(X^3(X-3)^3)\to M_5 (\mathbb Q)$.

To $x:=X\bmod(X^3(X-3)^3)$ corresponds by $f$ a matrix $A\in M_5(\mathbb Z)$ such that $A^3(A-3I)^3=0$. Then $\mu_A\in\mathbb Q[X]$, the minimal polynomial of $A$, satisfies $\mu_A\mid X^3(X-3)^3$. Moreover, $\deg\mu_A\le5$. Let's say that $\mu_A=X^i(X-3)^j$ with $i+j\le5$. Then $A^i(A-3I)^j=0$, that is, $f(x^i(x-3)^j)=0$. Since $f$ is injective we get $x^i(x-3)^j=0$. This means that $X^i(X-3)^j\in(X^3(X-3)^3)$, a contradiction.

Comment: Wonderful,Thanks a lot!